# Local git branches and stash backup

Tags: git, bitbucket

How do I get my local git branches and stash backup on my new machine from origin? 
I am shifting from windows to mac and have already changed the remote origin.

But still when am entering the "git branch" command, am seeing the local branches of the person who had this machine earlier.

Can anyone tell me the exact steps? Do I need to fetch or what?

Comment: Local branches and stashes are stored purely locally, you can’t get them back from the remote.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, local branches are local and therefore not available to remote machines. The standard and recommended procedure to make them available to other people is to push them to some remote. If you don't want to push to the exising `origin`, then create another remote, say `backup`. To that end, you first create an empty repository:

```
mkdir /tmp/x
cd /tmp/x
git init --bare
```

Then add this as a remote in your existing repository

```
git remote add backup file:///tmp/x
```

Now push your branch to that repository

```
git push --set-upstream backup your-branch
```

You can now copy the `x` repository to the new machine and clone from there. I don't have a Mac, but I just tried with Linux and Windows, and it worked.

For the stash, you could export each stash as diff. These diffs can be applied via `patch -p1` on the target machine. Then recreate the stash on the target. If you have several stashes, be careful to apply each diff to the same state as in the original.

Comment: If you successfully copy the `.git` directory to the new machine (taking care to remove the old one first) your stashes will be in there and you will not need to copy them!

Comment: I just updated my solution.  The original version can still be seen by clicking on the "edited ... ago" link.  I think instead of copying the `.git` directory to the machine it is safer to use git's standard mechanims. A remote repository can be a directory on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianW for the detailed information, but all my local branches are already present on my remote origin and I can view them in my bitbucket account as I used to push my branches to my origin earlier.
Now, when am fetching using `git fetch --all` on my friend's machine am getting authentication error. Fetch, pull and push - nothing is working.

Comment: @Jai You should have said that in the first place ;-) May be you should also clarify what you mean with _I am seeing the local branches of the person who had this machine earlier_ in your question. You are probably accessing the remote repo with that person's credentials. Have a look at `.git/config`, it should tell you. What happens if you do a clean `git clone` on the repo?

Comment: @AdrianW, `.git/config` gave permission denied error but `git clone` was not required again.
Problem got solved. I did `git remote set-url origin https://...` again due to some access issues and then `git fetch --all` to get all my origin and upstream branches.
I only couldn't get my local stashes back.